# Cómo poner un loader con porcentaje en video/audio html antes de que se cargue inicialmente?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3, audio, html-video

Actualmente estoy en un proyecto en vue done estoy creando un multi-reproductor de diferentes tipos de medias... y uno de los features que me solicitaron es colocar un loader de carga que dure el tiempo necesario antes de que se cargue el video o audio html.

No sé como tomar estos datos de carga para poder mostrarlos antes de cada la carga de video o audio..

Alguien me puede ayudar, al menos a saber si esto es posible? y como seria el proceso.

Mi idea es tomar este valor para mostrar un porcentaje junto a un loader .svg y cuando termine que ésto se oculte o se vaya.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Si es posible, además creo que `<video>` ya incluye un spinner

Comment: Si, pero necesito colocar uno personalizado que arroje un valor al principio en porcentaje de carga del video antes de arrancar